Ubuntu not working after Nvidia driver change
Today I was planning on installing nvidia-550 driver on my Ubuntu 24.04 install after having a good year's worth of runtime with nouveau driver, which served me quite well on my Lenovo laptop with an RTX 4070.
I went into the app named Software & Update and clicked on nvidia 550 drivers (proprietary & tested), and the installer asked me to reboot my system. I did that and horror struck me as I realized my USB keyboard, touchpad, Bluetooth, wifi nothing was working. Screen display was stuck at 60HZ with no option to choose otherwise. Tried uninstalling nvidia using sudo apt purge nvidia-* and that returned no packages found.
Since then I've reverted to Xorg noveau but that has not fixed my issues, system is barely usable. I have never experienced such a disaster on one nvidia driver install. The only option left for me it seems is to do a full reinstall which will take some time as I need to backup my data. If something can be done to avoid that, I would appreciate the advice.

A simulation apt -s remove $(dpkg -l | grep nvidia | awk '{print $2}')

I also have issues with the 550-drivers. The 535 working fine for me (including the bugs/performance due to an older version). I use the Razer Core X Chroma as an eGPU with an 4070 too.
